# Can't get bundle exec to work in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I've installed my gems in production with:

```
cd /app/releases/current && bundle install --gemfile /app/releases/current/Gemfile --path /app/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test
```

I can't `bundle exec` any of my gems (except `rake` and `gem`):

```
$ bundle exec whenever
bundler: command not found: whenever
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

The gems are correctly installed in /app/shared/bundle:

```
$ cd /app/shared
$ find . -name whenever
./bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/whenever-0.6.8/bin/whenever
./bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/whenever-0.6.8/lib/whenever
```

My (generated) bundle config (in /app/current/.bundle/config) is:

```
---
BUNDLE_FROZEN: "1"
BUNDLE_PATH: /app/shared/bundle
BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: "1"
BUNDLE_WITHOUT: development:test
```

I'm running ruby 1.9.2p290, manually installed to /usr/local/bin.

Do I have to `bundle install` my gems with the `--binstubs` option? Why wouldn't `bundle exec` be searching the stored `BUNDLE_PATH`?

Comment: I had a similar problem I solved with `bundle install --deployment`. I'm not sure **why** that worked, so that's why this is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: My capistrano task is including the `--deployment` argument when running `bundle install`. Is that what you mean? Or do you mean, remove the `--path` argument?

Comment: Are you using capistrano or doing manual deployments?

Comment: I'm deploying with Capistrano, using the builtin Bundler helpers by requiring `bundler/capistrano`. That's what's generating the `bundle install` command in my question.

Comment: Does `bundle show` list the `whenever` gem in production?

Comment: `bundle show` lists the `whenever` gem correctly in production. `bundle show whenever` has the right path: `/app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/whenever-0.6.8`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the `--path` from `/app/shared/bundle` to `vendor/bundle`, which made it work.

This seemed wrong to me, so I removed `/app/shared/bundle` and `vendor/bundle`, and ran `bundle install` again to `/app/shared/bundle`.

This clean `bundle install` fixed the problem. I have no idea why!

If anyone has an explanation for this, I'd love to mark you as the accepted answer. But this fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 8):

Using Capistrano and Rails and using deploy.rb as deployer file.

I realized that changing the order where appears `require "whenever/capistrano"` really matters. I put that at almost the last line:

In deploy.rb:

```
#first lines:
set :rvm_ruby_string, "1.9.3"
set :rvm_type, :user
set :whenever_command, "bundle exec whenever"

# others...

# last lines
require 'rvm/capistrano'
require 'bundler/capistrano'
require "whenever/capistrano"

after "deploy:update_code", "customs:config"
after "deploy:create_symlink","deploy:create_symlink"
after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup"

load 'deploy/assets'
# end
```

Comment: This solution put me on the right track, but did not work as described. Putting 'require "bundler/capistrano"' on the first line of deploy.rb and 'require "whenever/capistrano"' on the last line did it for me.

Comment: Seems that `require "bundler/capistrano"` should come before `require "whenever/capistrano`, so that `bundle:install` will happen before `whenever:update_crontab`.  See comment by javan [here](https://github.com/javan/whenever/issues/275)

Comment: This is not related, but why do you have this line?
`after "deploy:create_symlink","deploy:create_symlink"`

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem and had the requires in the correct order, i.e.

```
require 'rvm/capistrano'
require 'bundler/capistrano'
require 'whenever/capistrano'
```

It still wanted to run the crontab update before bundle:install.  The solution was to update my local bundler with

```
gem update bundler
```

After that it started working again.  Not sure exactly what changed between versions that broke all of this.

Comment: Thank you for your note that you needed to update your LOCAL bundler. I had everything in the right order and had checked the production server to make sure it had the latest version etc., but was still getting the error. Once I updated my local bundler everything worked.

As noted in this bundler issue https://github.com/javan/whenever/issues/275 bundler and whenever were in the process or working out the right capistrano hooks to use.

Comment: What is the difference between `bundler/capistrano` and `capistrano/bundler` ? I have the later in my Capfile.

Answer (score 1):

Check where your bundle:install is being set, and try moving it above require 'whenever/capistrano' in your deploy.rb file.

It seems like this was triggered when I did a bundle update that increased the whenever gem version in my Gemfile.lock.

It looks like whenever tries to run it's chrontab update before my deploy file runs bundle:install

from https://github.com/javan/whenever/blob/master/lib/whenever/capistrano.rb

```
before "deploy:finalize_update", "whenever:update_crontab"
```

And my deploy.rb had

```
after 'deploy:finalize_update', 'bundle:install'
```

Like everyone else in this thread, I tried a few things and I'm not sure this is what fixed it for me, but changing bundle install to before deploy:finalize_update, and also setting it as "before" above requiring 'whenever/capistrano' seems like it's the likely fix in my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I think when whenever gem is not in your `Gemfile`, or it's in the test or development section of your `Gemfile`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have `gem 'whenever'` in the main body of my Gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

Probably different issues cause the same error message. For me, I had to update capistrano gem after having updated whenever gem to get roles support. bundle exec whenever had worked prior to my upgrade of whenever.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [brightbox deployment gem](https://github.com/brightbox/brightbox-deployment/blob/master/lib/brightbox/recipes/bundler.rb), which handles bundler etc for me (by magic, in some other recipes) I found this works:

Replace

```
require "whenever/capistrano"
```

with the contents of https://github.com/javan/whenever/blob/master/lib/whenever/capistrano/v2/hooks.rb
then modify it to load after bundler:install finishes (you may or may not have that task, I don't know if it's standard)

```
# require "whenever/capistrano"
# hacked whenever/lib/whenever/capistrano/v2/hooks.rb below to work with brightbox bundler installation

require "whenever/capistrano/v2/recipes"

# Write the new cron jobs near the end.
after "bundler:install", "whenever:update_crontab"
# If anything goes wrong, undo.
after "deploy:rollback", "whenever:update_crontab"
```